# Mac OS X equivalent header file for `sysinfo.h` in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, porting, sysinfo

Is there any Mac OS X equivalent header file for `sysinfo.h` in Linux. I am porting code from Linux to Mac but the structure `struct sysinfo` is not found.

Edit: ==More info==
In Linux platform I use a Header file `<sys/sysinfo.h>` which is not found in Mac.
By including the header in Linux I perform following operation:
`struct sysinfo s;`
`sysinfo(&s);`

Which in result give me some system related info.
Now as I porting my project from Linux to Mac I want to know is there any similar functionality serve by Mac.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be better served asking how to achieve your ultimate aim rather than asking for the OS X equivalent of a Linux header file.

Comment: I edit my post....could you please see it one more time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What information are you trying to get? load, uptime, memory usage etc?

Comment: [link](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sysinfo.htm) these are the values return by Linux. Can I have these values in Mac or some of these values. Thanks again.

Comment: I think @duskwuff has told you how to access pretty much all the information returned by `sysinfo` on Linux.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The closest equivalent to `sysinfo` in Mac OS X is `sysctl` / MIB. It doesn't return a `sysinfo` struct directly, but most of the values in that structure are available as sysctl keys. For instance:

- `uptime` is approximated by `kern.boottime` (although that reflects the actual boot time, not the running time)
- `loads` is available as `vm.loadavg`
- `totalram` = `hw.memsize` (in bytes)
- `freeram`, `sharedram`, and `bufferram` are complicated, as the XNU memory manager works differently from Linux's. I'm not sure if the closest equivalent values ("active" and "inactive" memory) are exposed.
- `totalswap` and `freeswap` are reflected in `vm.swapusage`. (But note that OS X allocates swap space dynamically.)
- `procs` doesn't appear to have any equivalent.
- `totalhigh` and `freehigh` are specific to i386 Linux.

Comment: Can you explain how I can access this data from a C program?

Comment: Yes; use the `sysctlbyname()` function in libSystem.